# shallow copying of data type with heap objects and destruction conflict

Tags: c++, destructor, shallow-copy

I have the following data type:

```
class A{
public:
    A(){
    }
    ~A(){
        for(size_t i=0; i<b_elements.size(); i++)
            delete b_elements[i];
        b_elements.clear();
    }
    vector<B*> b_elements;
    //other operations ...
};
```

A visitor design pattern is implemented to do some calculations on `A`.

The problem starts when I want to work on a subset of `b_elements` only and to apply the visitor on specifically those elements.

One solution would be to create another object of `A` with its `b_elements` pointing to the desired elements in the original object and calling the visitor on the newly created object. But (as you would expect) the problem is when the new object is destroyed, the destructor will delete those references which will affect the original object as a side effect.

**Hint:** I cannot create a copy from the original object with the desired `b_elements` because it is too expensive.

My question is, is this a common pattern? and what is the best practice to avoid such problem?

Answer (score 2):

Store vector of shared pointers:

```
class A{
public:
    A(){
    }
    vector<std::shared_ptr<B>> b_elements;
    //other operations ...
};
```

Comment: Note that this solution will keep those objects of class `B` around until you delete both object of class `A`. If you want to automatically invalidate all the references in the "smaller" `A` object (i.e. if that object has just the semantic of a "view" on the bigger one), then you have to find another solution.

Comment: I don't have good knowledge about shared_ptr, but as far as I understand it is a reference-counting data type that gets destroyed when the number of references is zero, and upon destruction it will automatically deallocate (delete) the object it references, hence there is no need for A's destructor anymore, is this correct?

Comment: @H.Josef that is correct. The compiler-synthesized destructor will do.

Comment: ok thanks guys, it is a very clean, useful, and simple solution. However, I would prefer not to incorporate C++11 concepts into my code because it will probably be compiled using 'old' compilers. I am also interested in better design suggestions.
Thanks again.

Comment: @H.Josef you can use shared_ptr from boost which behaves the same way and is supported on reasonably old compilers.

Comment: @yurikilochek yeah I just read about that, unfortunately, I am working in the field of high performance computing and their backends are somehow old :( so linking against Boost is not a very good idea because not all compilers they are using support it

Comment: @H.Josef shared_ptr in boost is header only, its unlikely you will have any problems.

Comment: There is also `std::tr1::shared_ptr` which is supported, for example, in Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 1):

Or a shared pointer for the vector

```
class A{
public:
    A(){
    }
    std::shared_ptr< std::vector<B*> > b_elements;
    //other operations ...
};
```

With this approach, only the vector will be destroyed at the end, and not it's elements.